# Why the text of this TextView is not changed?

Tags: android, onkeydown

Firstly I have to say that I have been like 2 weeks researching on this, but didn´t found the answer to this...

I have a TextView, so which I want to do is to change its text with the keycode of any hardware keypress (yes, I know some of keypresses cannot be used)... The problem is that the text doest want to change... Anyone please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks a lot!!!

Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class keycodelistener extends Activity {

    private TextView txtcode;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.keycodedialog);

        txtcode = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.keypresstext);

    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        txtcode.setText(String.valueOf(keyCode));
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Finally, it worked with this thanks to @CFlex !!! last three lines must be:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     //Log.e("","yeeeahhhh");
     txtcode.setText(String.valueOf(keyCode));
     return true;

}
```

Comment: Have you checked that onKeyDown is being fired?

Comment: sorry, but how could i do that?

Comment: @BamsBamx Use Log.d(String tag, String msg). Then check your logcat.

Comment: You could create a log output, a Toast, or any number of other methods.

Comment: In most cases when a key is clicked the actvity pauses so why dont you put this code inside onPause()?

Comment: @Jon Taylor,Gabriel Casado so, when I press any hardware key, it must be shown in the logcat, right? Okay, i added that command into onKeyDown... It doesnt appear anything :(

Comment: look at @CFlex answer below, you are trying to override a method which does not exist in the super class.

Comment: @jaisonDavis how to do that, please, i have never used onPause()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to Override `onKeyDown(keyCode, event)` because `onKeyDown(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` does not exist. Doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    /* do what you want */
}
```

Hope this was helpfull.

Comment: This is why I often find it useful to put the `@Override` annotation above any method I believe I am overriding, my IDE will tell me if I am trying to override something that does not exist in a super class.

Comment: Yup, @Override can literally make or break the day. :)

Comment: this is wrong, something must be returned... is this ok to return?: return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

Comment: @BamsBamx It is not wrong, he was merely pointing out the method which you should be overriding, not what should be in its body.  You will still need to return a boolean value, whether you choose to call super.onKeyDown is up to you.

Comment: @BamsBamx Read the doc please: "Return true to prevent this event from being propagated further, or false to indicate that you have not handled this event and it should continue to be propagated."